# Java compiler api error

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile in-memory a class that implements an interface.

I have an interface named CacheRule (in com/vpfw/proxy/logicRules/CacheRule.class).

I have a class named `CacheRuleBean` that I compile in-memory.
If this class does not implement `CacheRule`, compilations works. But if this class implements `CacheRule`, then the error is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vpfw/proxy/logicRules/CacheRule (wrong name: com/vpfw/proxy/logicRules/CacheRuleBean)
```

Curiously, if I perform this compilation inside Eclipse, works.
But when I execute it from Tomcat, I get the previous error.

This is the code for the `CacheRule` interface:

```
package com.vpfw.proxy.logicRules;
public interface CacheRule
{
 void executeRule();
}
```

This is the code for `CacheRuleBean`:

```
package com.vpfw.proxy.logicRules;

import com.vpfw.proxy.logicRules.CacheRule;

public class CacheRuleBean implements CacheRule
{
 public void executeRule() {}
}
```

And the call to compile is:

```
String[] compilationOptions = { "-cp", classDir };

return (new CompilerService().compile("com.vpfw.proxy.logicRules.CacheRuleBean", 
                   source, compilationOptions));
```

Where

- `classDir` is the directory `/home/app/WEB-INF/classes` that contains the `com` folder of this project (classPath is correct, If I add another classes of this project as imports in `CacheRuleBean`, compile ok).
- The name of the class I use is `com.vpfw.proxy.logicRules.CacheRuleBean`.
- `source` is the source code of `CacheRuleBean`.
- `CompilerService` is my implementation of compiler API, which works perfectly with all classes except those that implement an interface.

What can I be doing wrong?